# How to build a 'tree'-like heiarchy with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a total newbie to Angular, but with a lot of experience in JQuery - so "Explaining Like I'm 5" would be really useful!

I've got a list of "Items", which are displayed in a folder (or 'tree') like hierarchy. Each may have a parent item.

```
Item 1
| - Item 2 (parent is 1)
| - Item 3 (parent is 1)
| - Item 4 (parent is 1)
    | - Item 6 (parent is 4)
| - Item 5 (parent is 1)
```

If it doesn't have a parent item, it will be attached to the Dom as the "top of the tree". If it does, then it should be attached in a div inside that item.

I can load the items from the database in Angular. How do I build the tree? I've heard that you should never do DOM manipulation outside of a directive - is this the case here?

**Attempt at a solution**

This is 'jQuery' thinking, but this is how I'd do it.

1. Load the items into an array.
2. Add the parentless items to the DOM
3. As each item is added, run a "Get children" function to find any children in the array and add them to the DOM

Comment: Use this module  http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

Comment: maybe this module, or the source for it, might help: https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

Comment: google `angular recursive tree` will find modules, examples and tutorials. It is simpler than you think using nested  repeating directive